# Why I got this error:python 2.7 class TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments

Tags: python, class

class Worker:

```
def _init_(self,name,pay):
    self.name=name
    self.pay=pay
def lastName(self):
    return self.name.split()[-1]
def giveRaise(self,percent):
    self.pay*=(1.0+percent)
```

bob=Worker('Bob Smith',50000)

sue=Worker('Sue Jones',60000)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Dropbox\2013 SPRING\cs410\exercise.py", line 207, in <module>
    bob=Worker('Bob Smith',50000)
TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments

Answer (score 1):

You used a single underscore before and after `init`. Python uses two underscores before and after:

```
def __init__(self,name,pay):
    self.name=name
    self.pay=pay
```

Answer (score 0):

Also always inherit from the base type object. Your class declaration should be:

```
class Worker(object):
    def __init__(self,name,pay):
        self.name=name
        self.pay=pay
    def lastName(self):
        return self.name.split()[-1]
    def giveRaise(self,percent):
        self.pay*=(1.0+percent)
```

Not inheriting from object makes an "old-style" class in Python 2.x. See http://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass for details, if you don't know, then you want new-style classes.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used to use python 2.7, now I just updated to 3.3.1, I found a lot of uncomfortable unknown changes, like fixing print becomes print(). Is there any summary about those changes?